# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 from WordPress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

I saw a couple of questions about this problem but couldn't solve it.

So I am trying to create a wordpress theme using ReactJS and with it I am fetching the wp-json with this code :

```
const postsUrl = './wp-json/wp/v2/posts';

fetch(postsUrl)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => {
    this.setState({
    posts: response
  });
});
```

Till now everything is fine. However, when I add :

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'container_class' => 'navigation_body', 'theme_location' => 'navigation_home'
));
```

in `function.php` I get this error in the browser console.

Error message : 
`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: also put error message in browser console.

Comment: It is in the title but okay. Done.

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: Seems like `fetch(postsUrl)` doesn't return json (maybe an error as string) so `response.json()` throws `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`. Double check what's the response..

Comment: I replaced it with .then(response => response.text()).then(console.log(response)... And it returned json in the console. Overall it returns json and everything works. However, when I add a nav menu in function.php and the response.json() is in use I get the error.

Comment: Maybe I found the problem but don't know how to solve it. So when I create a nav_menu somehow this HTML code goes into the wp-json (picture below). And response.json() cannot take it and returns an error: https://imgur.com/a/F4PLcCA